Mac Drag Windows to Menu Bar to Fill Screen Delay
In Sequoia 15.1.1, is there a way to edit the delay when dragging windows to the top to full screen them?
When I drag to the sides for 1/2 screen it's close to instant to snap, but when I drag to the menu bar up top there is a ~1sec delay baked in which is a bit annoying. Is there maybe a terminal command that can tweak this delay?
